# Can I use a pump to discharge kitchen sink waste water, rather than digging up the concrete?

Tags: plumbing, kitchens, basement

We are installing a small kitchen in the basement.  There is a full bathroom in the other corner of the area, same side as the planned kitchen.  I could use some experienced recommendations for the kitchen plumbing ... do we have the contractors dig up the concrete floor OR do we use a pump for the sink (only a sink will be installed, no dishwasher).  This is the last issue we need a decision on to start the renovations, which are a few weeks behind because we need some advise here.  The basement kitchen will not be used that often and, for expenses sake, I feel the pump would fit the bill.  Any reason why not?

Comment: We can give a better answer if you have current bath layout including how it connects to the main stack.

Comment: Venting the drain is important, so you need to know how the bathroom is configured. You may be able to gravity feed the sink to existing drains.

Answer (score 1):

I'd really need pictures to answer properly, But it is entirely possible that you wouldn't even need a pump.  Your kitchen sink should be high enough that you can run a properly sloped horizontal run to connect to the drain pipe behind the kitchen sink.

Answer (score 1):

You need to locate the waste pipe for the bathroom. It sounds like it's in the wall where you plan to put the sink. If the bathroom toilet or sink are on the other side of the wall, then you should be able to connect to their waste pipe as @Chris says.